# What is the softening temperature of styrofoam?

Tags: polymers, hydrocarbons

Does anybody know the softening temperature of styrofoam (expanded polystyrene)?

By styrofoam I mean the solid made of expanded polystyrene balls used in packaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different [temperatures one could consider the softening point](https://www.creativemechanisms.com/blog/polystyrene-ps-plastic) of atactic (randomly distributed phenyl groups) polystyrene, used in making expanded polystyrene :

- Softening point: [~90 °C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polystyrene)
- Heat Deflection Temperature: 95 °C
- Typical Injection Molding Temperature: [from 170 °C at back to 230 °C at nozzle](https://plastics.ulprospector.com/generics/43/c/t/polystyrene-ps-properties-processing/sp/4)

Comment: Not to mention softening point is effected on thermal history and residual stress.

Comment: And chemical composition (phenyl  distribution etc.)